# Javascript button to set checkbox true if conditions are met

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox

I keep getting 'unexpected token ==' when the button is clicked. I have been through the code and everything looks right to me. Can anyone see why?
All field names are correct.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}

if({!Delegate__c.VC_Profile_ID__c} == ""
&& ({!Delegate__c.Online_SAP_Course__c} == "TR_ELE_037"
|| {!Delegate__c.Online_SAP_Course__c} == "TR_ELE_038"
|| {!Delegate__c.Online_Course_Name__c} == "18th Edition Full"
|| {!Delegate__c.Online_Course_Name__c} == "18th Edition Update")
&& {!Delegate__c.Delegate_Email__c} != "email@notprovided.com")
    {
     var newRecords = [];
     var del = new sforce.SObject("delegate__c");
     del.id ="{!Delegate__c.Id}";
     del.VCManualTrigger__c = true;
     newRecords.push(del);
     result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
     window.location.reload();
    }

else if({!Delegate__c.VC_Profile_ID__c}!= ""
&& {!Delegate__c.Delegate_Email__c} != "email@notprovided.com")
    {
     alert("This delegate is already on Virtual College, us the profile link to view")
    }

else if({!Delegate__c.Delegate_Email__c} == "email@notprovided.com")
    {
     alert("Invalid delegate email address")
    }
else
    {
     alert("Error")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your apex merge variables in quotes. They're directly printed into the javascript, which can be useful, but needs to be handled a certain way.

```
if("{!Delegate__c.VC_Profile_ID__c}" == "") { ... }
```

result:

```
if("001U000000ASKk1" == "") { ... }
```

Instead of:

```
if(001U000000ASKk1 == "") { ... }
```

Comment: Knew it would be something ridiculously simple! Thanks so much, working fine now

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put merge fields with double quotes as follows, other than this I dont find anything

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}

if("{!Delegate__c.VC_Profile_ID__c}" == ""
&& ("{!Delegate__c.Online_SAP_Course__c}" == "TR_ELE_037"
|| "{!Delegate__c.Online_SAP_Course__c}" == "TR_ELE_038"
|| "{!Delegate__c.Online_Course_Name__c}" == "18th Edition Full"
|| "{!Delegate__c.Online_Course_Name__c}" == "18th Edition Update")
&& "{!Delegate__c.Delegate_Email__c}" != "email@notprovided.com")
    {
     var newRecords = [];
     var del = new sforce.SObject("delegate__c");
     del.id ="{!Delegate__c.Id}";
     del.VCManualTrigger__c = true;
     newRecords.push(del);
     result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
     window.location.reload();
    }

else if("{!Delegate__c.VC_Profile_ID__c}" != ""
&& {!Delegate__c.Delegate_Email__c} != "email@notprovided.com")
    {
     alert("This delegate is already on Virtual College, us the profile link to view")
    }

else if("{!Delegate__c.Delegate_Email__c}" == "email@notprovided.com")
    {
     alert("Invalid delegate email address")
    }
else
    {
     alert("Error")
    }
```